# Find out whether the Bluetooth device detected is a printer device

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth

I am developing an Android printing application using Cordova using the 'Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer' plugin. While searching for Bluetooth devices, the result contains many devices. I would like to list only the printer devices in my result list. Is it possible to find whether the device detected is a printer device or not?

Comment: Look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getBluetoothClass()

Comment: Thank you for your replay but I need solution for Cordova development

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method to identify the printer devices. But you can make it possible by using unique name of the Bluetooth device. If you found the Bluetooth devices starting with that device name,you can take necessary actions.We got the same requirement like you. But we finally ended up with the mentioned solution.